# Reloading AucTex Labels and Defining Keybindings

Tags: emacs, auctex

When I add a label in emacs to a .tex file, I used to reload the file to get it to show up in RefTeX. i.e. C-c ) wouldn't have the new label unless I reloaded the file.

After some searching I found that C-u C-c ) will refresh RefTeX before trying to do the reference. This works as I would like, but I would like to use C-c r for this command instead of typing C-u C-c ) every time. How do I do this?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

I don't use reftex but as far as I can understand you want just to define a binding:

```
(define-key reftex-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'reftex-reference)
```

Comment: If I understand properly, this will just map C-c ) to C-c r. What I'm looking to do is map the sequence "C-u C-c )" to C-c r. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Building on Oleg's answer:

Maybe it would be better to feed it the C-u argument already if that's what you are after:

```
(defun call-reftex-reference-directly ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-prefix-arg 4)) ;; emulate C-u
    (call-interactively 'reftex-reference) ;; invoke reftex-reference 
  )
)
(define-key reftex-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'call-reftex-reference-directly)
```

Maybe try if this works for you?

Comment: a version of this works. Thanks a lot! Code is below: I just changed 4 --> 1 and defined a global key. For some reason "reftex-mode-map" was throwing an error.

(defun call-reftex-reference-directly ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-prefix-arg 1)) ;; emulate C-u                                  
    (call-interactively 'reftex-reference) ;; invoke reftex-reference           
  )
)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") 'vspace) ;

Answer (score 0):

You can type `r` in the label selection buffer to refresh it without reloading the file. The refresh is instantaneous (unless you have very large/very many linked files).

Comment: @user1769240 Great! It's customary on StackOverflow to upvote answers that are helpful, and to 'accept' the best one. You can upvote more than one answer, if you get multiple useful responses. You can only 'accept' one answer, but if you change your mind (or a better answer is posted after you accept one) you can change which answer you accept.